# NotifyDataSetChanged RecyclerView not working at all

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I am using a `RecyclerView` to show the data that is retrieved after parsing from the web services. The problem is `notifydatasetchanged` is not working at all. For solving that thing, I am setting the adapter again.

I am having two problems using this technique:

1. There is a screen blink while setting a new adapter again.
2. Also the recycler view points to first item of the recycler view. (I just want to append the new data at the end of the existing list.Array list size is updating. But the only problem, the list is started from the zeroth position.)

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book_mag_list_child, container, false);
       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.bookMagRecyclerViewList);
       bookMagDataList = new ArrayList<>();
       adapter = new BookMagListRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), bookMagDataList);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
       LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
       //linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
       recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
           @Override
           public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
               Log.d("Do Something", "Do Something" + current_page);
               params.setStart("" + current_page);
               dataModel.init(params);
           }
       });
       return view;
   }




   @Override
   public void update() {
       if (dataModel.getFragmentData(subScreenId) != null) {
           bookMagDataList = dataModel.getFragmentData(subScreenId);
           Log.d("MyDataListSize: ", "" + bookMagDataList.size());
           adapter = new BookMagListRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), bookMagDataList);
           recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

       }
   }
   ```

Please check what is the issue and let me know if it can be solved.

Comment: I have better way. Just add new data to older list in `Adapter class` and call  `notifyDataSetChanged();` from that.

Comment: I have done the same. The same we do in listview. Have u used with recycler view ?

Comment: If you want us to resolve an issue, show the issue, not the workaround

Comment: Yup done the same with recycler  View

Comment: I have an arraylist which has new data everytime I scoll the list. So it is not updating at all.

Comment: If you just want to add an item at the end then try using bookMagDataList.add(position, data); and then call notifyItemInserted(position); No need to call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: check my answer do it like that

Comment: I want to add 20items everytime @JyotmanSingh

Comment: Then first add all the items to the list like above and use notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) where position start is the position from which you start inserting and itemCount is the number of items inserted.

Comment: Please post the adapter code as well.

Comment: `int start = list.size();
    for (Object o : newItems){
        list.add(o);
    }
    adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(start, start+newItems.size()-1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your update function. You are overriding the bookMagDataList list with new instance everytime your update. You should have use .addAll() function to add in new element. Then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after that. Make changes as below.

```
 @Override
    public void update() {
        if (dataModel.getFragmentData(subScreenId) != null) {
            bookMagDataList.addAll(dataModel.getFragmentData(subScreenId));
            Log.d("MyDataListSize: ", "" + bookMagDataList.size());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Gaurav why are u keeping bookMagDataList in Fragment? is your adapter inner class?

Comment: @ankitagrawal maybe the activity that is hosting the fragment is not interested in knowing the implementation of the fragment? This will maximize the re-usability of the activity.

Comment: @styx i am not talking activity but Fragment and adapter , ideally fragment shouldnt have data but adapter should have

Comment: @ankitagrawal Ideally yes. The implementation of read/update/insert/delete also should be encapsulated in the adapter. Due to bad design i assume?

Comment: i guess upto him how to implement , he resolved his issue so no worries

Comment: @ankitagrawal true! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

since u didnt posted your adapter code u have to use styx approach:

```
@Override
public void update() {
    if (dataModel.getFragmentData(subScreenId) != null) {
        bookMagDataList.addAll(dataModel.getFragmentData(subScreenId));
        Log.d("MyDataListSize: ", "" + bookMagDataList.size());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

answer is given by styx so credits to him

Comment: Why override it with new instance when you can just add in the updated value in the original list using bookMagDataList.addAll() function? A reminder: The original List is reside in the fragment where the adapter only keep a reference of it.

Comment: did i override it with new instance , i just reuse the same adapter , please see the code

Comment: further we dont know if he is keeping a reference or not in adapter since he hasnt posted adapter code and also u are assuming that we dont know it

Comment: @ankitagrawal: If he hasn't posted the adapter code then we should ask him to post

Comment: If the adapter not keeping a reference of the list then how is the adapter suppose to display the data?

Comment: adapter keeps a local arraylist generally but since he didnt posted we dont know it yet

Comment: down care to explain

Answer (score 0):

my solution is below

```
if (adapter == null) {
    adapter = new BookMagListRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), bookMagDataList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  } else {
    adapter.bookMagDataList.clear();
    adapter.bookMagDataList = bookMagDataList;
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't instantiate  adapter again, only you should add new data in arrayList then invoke notifyDatasetChanged()

like--

```
bookMagDataList.add("YOUR ITEM");
adpter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to do like below in `update` method,

```
if(adapter == null){
    adapter = new BookMagListRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), bookMagDataList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}else{
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```